# Как убрать серые поля сверху и снизу карты при масштабе Яндекс карты-2

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Мне нужно показать карту мира, но при масштабе 2, появляются серые полосы, как сделать чтобы серых полос не было как в примере [Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/maps/?ll=16.012983%2C2.704728&z=2)

Серые полосы о которых речь на скриншоте
[image: Яндекс карта с серой областью]

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Если на странице есть контейнер для яндекс карты с id map_container, начинаем её формировать
    if($("#map_container").length > 0)  
        {

        //yandex map
        ymaps.ready(function() {
            var map = new ymaps.Map("map_container", {
                center: [55.738299999994, 37.5946], //Создаём карту с центром в городе "Ростов-на-Дону"
                zoom: 2,    //Увеличение 11
controls: ['zoomControl']
            },
{
    maxZoom: 17,
suppressMapOpenBlock: true,
noSuggestPanel: false,
checkZoomRange: true,
    minZoom: 2
}
);
                //Кластера - группируем близко расположенные друг к другу объекты, чтобы при отдалении карты появлялась другая иконка
                // с количеством объектов в данной точке 

                var ClusterContent = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="claster" >$[properties.geoObjects.length]</div>');

                //Параметры иконки кластера, обычно её делают отличной от точки, чтобы пользователь не путал номер объекта
                // и количество объектов

                var clusterIcons=[{
                    href: '/bitrix/templates/.default/images/balloon.png',
                    size:[48, 48],
                    offset:[-24, -80],
                }];

                //Создание самого кластера
                myClusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
                    clusterIcons: clusterIcons,
                    clusterNumbers:[1],
                    zoomMargin: [30],
                    clusterIconContentLayout: ClusterContent
                });


            //HTML шаблон балуна, того самого всплывающего блока, который появляется при щелчке на карту
             var myBalloonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                        '<address class="address-map" >'+
                 '<a href="$[properties.link]" target="_blank"><strong>$[properties.name]</strong></a>'+
                        '</address>'
                    );




                var Placemark = {}; //Пустой объекта, куда будут помещены точки на для карты

                //Перебираем все блоки с картой и считываем данные для формирования точки и балуна по ранее заданному шаблону
                $(".shop-data").each(function(){

                    //Координаты точки
                    var X = $(this).attr("data-yandex-x");
                    var Y = $(this).attr("data-yandex-y");
                    var img = $(this).attr("data-img");             
                        Obj = $(this).attr("pointindex");

                        //Создаём объект с заданными координатами и доп.свойствами
                        Placemark[Obj] = new ymaps.Placemark([X,Y], {
                            name: $(this).attr("data-name"),    //Наименование камеры
                            link: $(this).attr("data-link"),//детальная страница камеры
                            img: $(this).attr("data-img"),  //img
                            iconContent: "<div class='marker-circ'></div>", //Порядковый номер на карте
                    },{ //Ниже некоторые параметры точки и балуна
                        balloonContentLayout: myBalloonLayout,  
                        balloonOffset: [5,0],
                        balloonCloseButton: true,
                        balloonMinWidth: 450,
                        balloonMaxWidth:450,
                        balloonMinHeught:150,
                        balloonMaxHeught:200,
                        iconImageHref: '/bitrix/templates/.default/images/balloon.png', //Путь к картинке точки
                        iconImageSize: [48, 48],
                        iconImageOffset: [0, 0],// смещение картинки
                        iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
                        iconactive: '/bitrix/templates/.default/images/balloon.png' //Путь к картинке точки при наведении курсора мыши

                    });



                    //Добавляем маркер (точку) через кластер
                    myClusterer.add(Placemark[Obj]);
                  });

                //Добавление кластеры на карту
                map.geoObjects.add(myClusterer); 
                //Запрещаем изменение размеров карты по скролу мыши
            //map.behaviors.disable("scrollZoom");
map.behaviors.disable('drag');
                var clusterArray = objectManager.clusters.getAll();
                console.log('z1', clusterArray);
        }); 


        }
});
```

Comment: Покажите код или страницу с картой

Comment: http://world-cam.ru/world/

Answer (score 0):

У Вас по всей вероятности в браузере `zoom` стоит на `67` процентов. Нажмите `CTRL +`
Вот я записал https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4a5N/jyB2fcoQq , что при изменении зума самого браузера и у Яндекса эта полоса появляется, поставьте `зум браузера` у себя на `100%` (Нажатием двух кнопок `Контрол Плюс`). Ее не убрать и нет смысла, так как пользователи ее не видят.

Comment: На самом деле другие эту серую полосу видят, поэтому я сюда и обратился. У меня зум в браузере 100%, монитор, 21 дюйм. Возникает вопрос, почему при одинаковом зуме браузера в 100% и zoom карты- 2 в моей карте есть полосы, а в примере Яндекса нет. В примере Яндекса еще и максимальное вертикальное перетягивание ограничено

Comment: @Ярослав Александров Попробуйте добавить restrictMapArea: true

Comment: Добавляю крайние точки 82.36289330187576 -14.433022945530112
-79.1551108896816 -45.96820276022176
но в итоге существенно обрезает область карты

Comment: При restrictMapArea:true карта становится сплошной серой зоной
https://yadi.sk/i/PA3Xz6YKzAxVvA
https://yadi.sk/i/yTumXhLLk4Om2A

Answer (score 0):

Установите зону [restrictMapArea](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map.html#Map__param-options.restrictMapArea). Задаётся двумя противоположными углами карты. По вертикали стоит ограничиться 85 параллелями, по горизонтали охват должен быть менее 360 градусов. Например:

```
    restrictMapArea: [
        [85,-30],
        [-85,329.99]
    ]
```